# How can I move an element upside down while moving forward?

Tags: html, css

```css
.anim-cat-2 img {
  animation: animcats 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes animcats {
  0% {
    transform: translate(100px, 100px)rotate(-15deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(150px, -100px) rotate(15deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg) translate(200px, 100px);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(15deg)translate(250px, -100px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg)translate(300px, 100px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(15deg)translate(350px, -100px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg)translate(400px, 100px);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(15deg)translate(450px, -100px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg)translate(500px, 100px);
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(15deg)translate(550px, -100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg)translate(600 px, 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim-cat-2">
  <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/95927edf9e85ece73dac69ade623432c/tumblr_otrmgaTiin1vxe4v6o1_400.png" style="height: 130px;width: 180px;margin-top: 20px;">
</div>
```

i cant make it go smoothly forward in right tilt, its suppossed to make the right angle and move up and down moving forward. i already tried to change the degree, x n y axis but it still didnt work,please help me

Comment: It is not really clear what the question is. Can you provide any additional visual or info to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Run code snippet.

Although it makes the right angle, move up and down, it did'nt meets the expectation at the end of the animation.

```css
.anim-cat-2 img {
    animation: animcats 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes animcats {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0px,0px);
    } 
    8% {
      transform: rotate(9deg);
    }
    10% {
      transform:  translate(100px,150px);
    }
    20% {
      transform:rotate(-9deg) translate(100px,150px);   
    }
    30% {
      transform:  translate(200px,0px);
    }
    40% {
      transform: rotate(9deg) translate(200px,0px);             
    }
    50% {
      transform:  translate(300px,150px);
    }
    60% {
      transform: rotate(-9deg)  translate(300px,150px);             
    }
    70% {
      transform:  translate(400px,0px);
    }
    80% {
      transform: rotate(9deg) translate(400px,0px);
    }
    90% {
      transform: translate(500px,150px);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(-9deg) translate(500px,150px);          
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim-cat-2">
    <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/95927edf9e85ece73dac69ade623432c/tumblr_otrmgaTiin1vxe4v6o1_400.png" style="height: 130px;width: 180px;margin-top: 20px;">
</div>
```